# Collecting to map using Java Stream API

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

Here is my class objects of I need to collect:

```
public class InvestBalance {

    @JsonValue
    private List<Balance> balances;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Balance {

        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private LocalDate date;

        private BigDecimal value;
    }
}
```

I got a `List<InvestBalance.Balance>` from a database, and I need to group them by the `date` field, so I need to get a `Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal>`. Value must be a sum of bigDecimals.
How can I do it using Java Stream API?

Comment: You need to be more precise. If you have many value on one date, what do you need ? A sum ? A list of values ?

Comment: In case of multiple values on same date, what should be the value in map to that date key?

Comment: @notescrew It must be a sum of values on the same date

Comment: @BenjaminD It must be a sum of values on the same date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Balance::getDate,
                       Collectors.mapping(Balance::getValue, 
                                  Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)));
```

Or with a static import of Collectors.* to make it more readable:

```
list.stream()
   .collect(groupingBy(Balance::getDate, 
                    mapping(Balance::getValue, reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` to collect as `Map`

```
Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> res = 
      list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Balance::getDate, Balance::getValue, BigDecimal::add));
```